# Deploying into remote TC server from STS ( spring tool suite )

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite

I wanted to configure STS to deploy my application into remotely running tc server. When I try to add a new server from STS and select vmware vFabric tc server. I get error saying only local server is supported for this type.

Any one know how to setup a remote server on STS?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use this maven plugin that connects to a tomcat server:

http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/index.html

With more specific instructions here for tomcat 6:

http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/tomcat6-maven-plugin/usage.html

or replace 6 with 7 in the link for tomcat 7.

As far as I know, STS (eclipse) can only directly deploy to a local tomcat instance, but once you configure that plugin you can make a run configuration with the maven goal `tomcat6:redeploy` to easily deploy to your remote server.